# How to align equations in two columns

Tags: eqnarray

Here is my code:
‎

```
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:diff_inv}‎ 
‎&\mathcal{D}_1 I_{10}=I_{20}-\frac{3}{2}I_{01},\qquad &\mathcal{D}_2 I_{10}=I_{11}-\frac{3}{2}I_{10}I_{01},\\‎ 
‎&\mathcal{D}_1 I_{01}=I_{11}-\frac{5}{2}I_{10}I_{01},\qquad &\mathcal{D}_2 I_{01}=I_{02}-\frac{5}{2}I_{01}^2‎, ‎\nonumber\\‎ 
‎&\mathcal{D}_1 I_{10}=I_{20},\qquad &\mathcal{D}_2 I_{10}=I_{11},\label{eq:diff_inv_55}\\‎ 
‎&\mathcal{D}_1 I_{01}=I_{11}+\alpha\,I_{01}I_{01},\qquad &\mathcal{D}_2 I_{01}=I_{02}+I_{01}^2‎, ‎\nonumber‎
‎\end{eqnarray}‎
```

and here is the result:

[image]

But I want this alignment:

[image]

Comment: as zarko says but also avoid control characters in your input, `! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ‎ (U+200E)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either `align` or `alignat{n}` are meant for this kind of equations

[image]

The pattern is following: groups consist of `right & left` aligned elements and each group is separated by another ampersand `&`. For instance, there are two groups in your example

```
  right & left   &   right & left \\
```

`alignat{n}` is similar but does not add extra space between columns. `n` is mandatory and denotes a number of groups, in your case `2`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{D}_1 I_{10} &= I_{20} - \frac{3}{2}I_{01},
        & \mathcal{D}_2 I_{10} &= I_{11} - \frac{3}{2}I_{10 }I_{01}, \\
  \mathcal{D}_1 I_{01} &= I_{11} - \frac{5}{2}I_{10}I_{01},
        & \mathcal{D}_2 I_{01} &= I_{02} - \frac{5}{2}I_{01}^2,      \nonumber \\
  \mathcal{D}_1 I_{10} &= I_{20},
        & \mathcal{D}_2 I_{10} &= I_{11},                            \label{eq:diff_inv_55} \\
  \mathcal{D}_1 I_{01} &= I_{11} + \alpha\,I_{01}I_{01},
        & \mathcal{D}_2 I_{01} &= I_{02} + I_{01}^2,                 \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**
In your code is somewhere hidden character which not allow to compile it with pdfLaTeX. Now I rewrite equation (from scratch) and MWE works as expected :-)

Like this?

[image]

Use of `eqnaray` is deprecated. Better is use `align` of `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\mathcal{D}_1 I_{10}
    & = BI_{20} - \frac{3}{2} I_{01}    &   \mathcal{D}_1 I_{10}
                                                & = I_{11} - \frac{3}{2} I_{10} I_{10}          \\
\mathcal{D}_1 I_{01}
    & = I_{11}-\frac{5}{2}I_{10}I_{01}  &   \mathcal{D}_2 I_{01}
                                                & = I_{02} - \frac{3}{2} I_{01}^2       \notag  \\
\mathcal{D}_1 I_{10}
    & = I_{11}-\frac{5}{2}I_{10}I_{01}  &   \mathcal{D}_2 I_{10}
                                                & = I_{11}              \label{eq:diff_inv_55}  \\
\mathcal{D}_1 I_{01}
    & = I_{11}-\alpha I_{10}I_{01}      &   \mathcal{D}_2 I_{01}
                                                & = I_{02} + I_{01}^2                   \notag  
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to edit my answer and edited yours by accident.

Comment: @Celdor, its happen ... I reject it so, no changes in my :-)