# How to write this multiline formula in Latex?

Tags: math-mode

Does anyone how to write this formula in Latex?
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym}
\begin{document}
$$R (A, B, C) \cup P (D, E, F) = Q (A, B, C)$$
% a b c     m n o     a b c
% d e f     g h i     d e f
% g h i               g h i
% j k l               j k l
%                     m n o.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `latexsym` package was superseded by the `amssymb` package in 1994 [!]. For sure, ever since then, there's no need or reason to load `latexsym` if `amssymb` is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use an `array`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{*{4}{c@{}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{}}}
    R( & A, & B, & C & ) \cup P( & D, & E, & F & ) = Q( & A, & B, & C) \\
       & a  & b  & c &           & m  & n  & o &        & a  & b  & c  \\
       & d  & e  & f &           & g  & h  & i &        & d  & e  & f  \\
       & g  & h  & i &           &    &    &   &        & g  & h  & i  \\
       & j  & k  & l &           &    &    &   &        & j  & k  & l  \\
       &    &    &   &           &    &    &   &        & m  & n  & o.
\end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with 3 top-aligned `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}     % default: 5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % default: 1
R(\begin{array}[t]{@{} lll @{}}
  A, & B, & C \\
  a  & b  & c \\
  d  & e  & f \\
  g  & h  & i \\
  j  & k  & l 
\end{array}) 
\cup
P(\begin{array}[t]{@{} lll @{}}
  D, & E, & F \\
  m  & n  & o \\
  g  & h  & i 
\end{array})
=
Q(\begin{array}[t]{@{} lll @{}}
  A, & B, & C \\
  a  & b  & c \\
  d  & e  & f \\
  g  & h  & i \\
  j  & k  & l \\
  m  & n  & o
\end{array})
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either `array` and control set column alignment to `l`eft, `c`entre, or `r`ight or use `alignat{n}` with groups of `right & left` alignment (see this [quation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654971/how-to-align-equations-in-two-columns/654975#654975))

[image]

EDIT. Please see the comment regarding the package `latexsym`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{c @{\;}c@{\;} c @{\ }c@{\ } c}
    R(A,B,C) &\cup& P(D,E,F) &=& Q(A,B,C) \\
    a b c    &    & m n o    & & a b c \\
    d e f    &    & g h i    & & d e f \\
    g h i    &    &          & & g h i \\
    j k l    &    &          & & j k l \\
             &    &          & & m n o
  \end{array}
\]

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    R(A,B,C) &\;\cup\;&& P(D,E,F) &\;=\;& Q(A,B,C) \\
    a b c    &        && m n o    &     & a b c \\
    d e f    &        && g h i    &     & d e f \\
    g h i    &        &&          &     & g h i \\
    j k l    &        &&          &     & j k l \\
             &        &&          &     & m n o
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `latexsym` package was superseded by the `amssymb` package in 1994 [!]. For sure, no need or reason to load `latexsym` if `amssymb` is loaded.

Comment: I am usually not trying to mess with OP's list of packages but didn't realise someone would bring an almost 30 years old one. I'll add a suggestion.

Comment: My bad -- I had completely missed the fact that the OP's code loads `latexsym`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for pointing this out. It's definitely important to know if someone is still trying to use those kind of files. Otherwise, I wouldn't be aware of that, at all.